# Magento 2.3, cannot get attribute ts_dimensions_height within product loop

Tags: magento2.3

We are trying to build a shipping plugin, however have run into a hurdle trying to retrieve values for ts_dimensions_height, ts_dimensions_width and ts_dimensions_length.

Our constructor looks like so:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    // \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory        
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->orderItemRepository = $orderItemRepository;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    // $this->eavFactory = $eavFactory;
    $this->regionFactory = $regionFactory;        
}
```

While in the Product object, we have tried all of the following:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute('ts_dimensions_height');

$product->getResource()->getAttribute('ts_dimensions_width');
```

NOTE: we do not have an issue getting other product data. E.g. getWeight, getSku, getName all work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get that attribute's value using this..

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productId = 2; //Product ID
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    $attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'ts_dimensions_height',1); //ts_dimensions_width
    var_dump($attributeValue);
?>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Worked! I needed to reload the product within the loop. The data I required was not available for the object in the loop.